# How to Convert listView to RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with use listView,because i display many Image in listview (about memory)

I need to convert listview to recyclerview

Problem:

> When I display the images, on my phone, using last view, you do a lot of memory blocking,
>   And it caused the application to stop, so I want to convert List View to RecycleView.

MainActivity:

```
    package com.masreta87.hussain

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.get
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.jar.Manifest
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T
import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.ExtraData
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var Img:ListView
    lateinit var ImgArr:ArrayList<DataImg>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         Img=findViewById(R.id.listviewB)
         ImgArr=ArrayList()

        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.h))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.hh))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.hhh))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v2))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v3))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v4))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v5))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v6))
        //ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v7))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v8))
        ImgArr.add(DataImg(R.drawable.v9))

        Img.adapter=customAdapter(applicationContext,ImgArr)
        Img.setOnItemClickListener{parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long ->
         var ImgNa=ImgArr.get(position).image.toString()

            Log.d("this",ImgNa)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )
                    !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        ,100)

                }else{
                    saveImageToStorage(ImgNa)
                }
            }else{
                saveImageToStorage(ImgNa)
            }

        }


    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode==100){
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

               // saveImageToStorage(ImgNa)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"No Permission for save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
    }
    public fun saveImageToStorage(ImgNa:String){

        val externalStorageState=Environment.getExternalStorageState()
        if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            val storeDirectory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            val rnds = (1000..100000000000).random().toString()
            val file=File(storeDirectory,"$rnds.png")//Namephoto
            try {

                Log.d("output",ImgNa)
                val stream:OutputStream =FileOutputStream(file)
                var drawable=ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext,ImgNa.toInt()) //edit
                var bitmap=(drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream)
                stream.flush()
                stream.close()
                Toast.makeText(this,"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"unable to access the storage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And customAdapter

```
package com.masreta87.hussain

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView

class customAdapter(var context: Context,var data:ArrayList<DataImg>) :BaseAdapter(){
private class ViewHolder(row:View?){
     var ivImage:ImageView
    init {
        this.ivImage=row?.findViewById(R.id.imageViewN) as ImageView


    }
}
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var view:View?
        var viewHolder:ViewHolder
        if(convertView==null){
            var layout=LayoutInflater.from(context)
            view=layout.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,parent,false)
            viewHolder=ViewHolder(view)
            view.tag=viewHolder

        }else{
            view=convertView
            viewHolder=view.tag as ViewHolder
        }
        var data:DataImg=getItem(position) as DataImg

        viewHolder.ivImage.setImageResource(data.image)
        return view as View
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return data.get(position)
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return data.count()
    }

}
```

And DataImg:

```
package com.masreta87.hussain

class DataImg(var image:Int) {

}
```

activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewN"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You just need to create recyclerview adapter instead of listview adapter and use same view as in this example and set it up in the activity

Comment: Alternative approach....I suggest you go for a glide image library it will cache your drawable in memory. you will not get any error out of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st change you activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you'll have to create an Adapter for RecyclerView like this:

```
class CustomAdapter(private val activity: Context?, private val arrData: List<DataImg>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var itemView: View? = null
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
                .inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        val model = arrData[i]
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrData.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {

    }

}
```

Now in your main activity you'll have to set Layout Manager for your RecyclerView and have to bind Adapter with it

```
recyclerViewSearchList = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
recyclerViewSearchList.adapter = CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, ImgArr)
```

Comment: recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
recyclerViewSearchList.adapter = CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, ImgArr)

error here

Comment: Make sure you are writing CustomAdapter not customAdapter with small C

Comment: Have you initialized recyclerview using
recyclerViewSearchList = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

Comment: recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)  //here error what recyclerView element??